# Set NSIS installation directory from command line when MUI is used?

Tags: nsis, modern-ui

I'm trying to write a [Scoop app manifest](https://github.com/lukesampson/scoop/wiki/App-Manifests) for a program ([JAGS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/JAGS/4.x/Windows/)) with a NSIS installer. I want to run the installer from PowerShell.

The NSIS documentation says to use the `/D` switch to set the installation directory. However, the installer uses NSIS's MUI macro to allow setting the directory in the graphical installer. For some reason, this doesn't respect the `/D` switch. Is there another way to force NSIS MUI to install to a particular directory?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with MUI, it is because they are using the MultiUser header file.

`/D` just sets `$InstDir` before any code in the installer runs and MultiUser changes `$InstDir` in `.onInit` overriding anything set with `/D`.

You can trick it to believe it is already installed:

```
!define JAGS_VERSION ??? ; I don't know which version but you probably do, or check your registry
WriteRegStr HKCU "SOFTWARE\JAGS\JAGS-${JAGS_VERSION}" "InstallDir" "c:\new dir for single user"
WriteRegStr HKLM "SOFTWARE\JAGS\JAGS-${JAGS_VERSION}" "InstallDir" "c:\new dir for all users"
```